# Does vector in ARGV mean one-dimensional array?

Tags: c, argv

Just curious about the term vector in programming field?

Comment: The vector tag has a concise definition.

Comment: At the time that `argv` became standard usage, there was no common use of the word `vector` to mean a specific data type (as in C++).  I don't remember if the `v` in `argv` means "vector" or "values" or what, but it is a one-dimensional array of argument values.

Comment: Interestingly the argv can also be seen as a 2-d-array (array of array of chars).

Comment: @steveha: At the time that `argv` became standard usage, C++ didn't even exist yet.  It harks back to K&R C from 1978, I believe.

Comment: @Thilo: Nope, it can't, arrays are not pointers.  It's an array of pointers, not an array of arrays.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield -- yes, that is true.  And no other language at the time used `vector` as a data type either, as far as I know, which was the point.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Sorry I don't quite get the `elaborate` in your comment.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, string itself are array of char

Comment: @AdamRosenfield So what argv[] does is passing the an array of pointers to the main function, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, I just checked my copy of _The C Programming Language_ by Kernighan and Ritchie, and that says that `argv` means "argument vector".  As far as I'm concerned, that settles it; it was probably Dennis Ritchie who chose that name anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here "vector" means a one-dimensional array.  This is a bit confusing because to represent a mathematical vector also uses a one-dimensional array, to store the coordinates in each of the dimensions, but this is a different usage.  In this case, "vector" bring up an image of all of the elements of the array laid out in a line.

Comment: In this particular case (the C argv array). "In programming field" it can mean all kinds of other things.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out! it makes so much sense to have array one to one mapping to the mathematical vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to C, C++ or Perl (all of which use the term "argv", though Perl is the only one in which it's usually capitalized as "ARGV"): yes, it means a one-dimensional array.

The term "vector" has other uses, but they're usually pretty close to "one-dimensional array" too. For instance, the C++ standard library defines a family of `vector` types, which behave like extensible arrays.

(There are other uses -- for instance, "interrupt vectors" -- that have nothing to do with this. I assume you aren't interested in those.)